# MongoDB programmatic collection creation/deletion costs

Tags: mongodb

I do have following requirements to implement:

1. create collection programmatically
2. add stream listeners (can be up to 10k listeners at a time)
3. push and read data to this collection and have all listeners nofified

Number of collections created at same time might be very large as well

How "costly" or "heavy" this scenario for MongoDB is it designed for such scenarios?

Comment: 2 pounds each. In which units you expect estimation of "cost" and "weight"? Having 10k open connections is not something impossible yet you may need some tuning - memory like 1MB per connection + db itself, file handlers like in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#number-of-connections etc.

Comment: please don't stick to units, it's rather question if mongo design for such scenarios, for example rabbitmq is more suitable for such case  BUT it could not support gathering messages was sent before you connected to listen for updated, thats why I'm considering mongo